# TFS 2013 Label build Issue

Tags: tfs

I have a build definition which builds and drops in to drop folder after build is completed.

Now i have label version of that in drop folder.

When I'm trying to queue build with Label added is it possible that TFS will not again rebuild project it just has to copy file from drop folder to destination.

I don't want windows workflow model I'm using MS Build parameters to do this,.

In other words how do i use X Copy in TFS with Ms Build.

Comment: Not sure I follow, all TFS Builds from 2010 onwards use the Windows Workflow model.

Comment: thanks Dyian for response.